# Polynomials in $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $F(x, y, z)$ - homogeneous polynomial degree six, such that the set of real solutions equation $F(x, y, z)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is finite. How many solutions can be?

My attempt:

Obviously, $F=\prod_{i=1}^6 (a_ix+b_iy+c_iz)$. Some of line can be equal, so answer is from 0 to 6. (Example for zero is $F=x^6+y^6+z^6$.)

Am I true?

Comment: I don't see how $x^6+y^6+z^6$ is of the form $\prod_{i=1}^6 (a_ix+b_iy+c_iz)$.

Comment: @Arthur, Then, maybe, $F$ is a product of some equations for $(0,0,0)$ and some equations for lines.